# gnuplot working via Shell, C Interface doing nothing at all

Tags: c, shell, gnuplot, pipe, raspbian

Working under Raspian, i have 2 Setups where i am generating 6 gnuplots in a C-program (with pipes). I have gnuplot 4.6, patchlevel 0 installed on both. 
Setup A: Everything works as expected.
Setup B: The plots are not generated. I started to investigate some time, downloaded the examples for the [C-Interface](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i-2.11.tar.gz). It compiled and executed the examples without error, but no images showed up. when i entered the commands via shell manually (for example sine.png)

```
gnuplot
gnuplot> set terminal png
gnuplot> set output sine.png
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

the output is generated as expected.

Conclusion: I suppose I am missing some librarys on system B. but since nothing is actively complaining, I don't know where to start searching?

Comment: What are the difference between "setup A" and "setup B"? When you can answer that you probably have your answer to this question.

Comment: you can print all of the linked libraries with ldd : http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ldd.htm

Comment: @JoachimPileborg setup A is my "prototyping system" based on Model B. I worked on since January and installed a whole lot of different needed and unneeded software on. Now i have to switch to setup B because I need more USB-Ports (Model B+).

Comment: If you have any redirection to `/dev/null` going on in your shell scripts (a common practice with std-err is `cmd > outFile 2>/dev/null` (there are several other variants, just search for `/dev/null`)), remove the redirection. You may find some error messages there. Good luck.

Comment: @specializt I just ldd'ed my gnuplots - all the librarys present on system A are also present on system B. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

By hazard I figured out what the problem was - speed. I found out that placing a

```
sleep(x.y);
```

in between my code is solving the problem. Since I'm not working on a time critical application and the code doesn't have to be optimized, the problem for me is solved. 
Apparently on windows this issue is well known, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349538/gnuplot-c-from-windows-command-window-opens-and-closes).
 Still unclear to me why this would happen on the newer hardware only.